# Primefaces fileUpload valueChangeListener doesn't trigger method

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, valuechangelistener

What am i missing here? valueChangeListener doesn't trigger method.

Screen Code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload id="filePath"
                  writeToMB="relationCompanyFileReferenceMB"
                  writePathTo="setFilePath"
                  writeSubjectTo="setFileName"
                  fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleDocumentUpload}"
                  valueChangeListener="#{companyController.onSaveRelationCompanyFileReference}"
                  mode="advanced"
                  auto="true"
                  onchange="submit();"
                  process="@this"
                  update=":editorCompanyFinancials:pnlFilePath"
                  sizeLimit="50000000"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|docx?|xlsx?)$/" locale="#{sessionBean.language}" label="Upload"
                  value="#{relationCompanyFileReferenceMB.model.filePath}"/>
</h:form>
```

Java Code:

```
public void onSaveRelationCompanyFileReference(ValueChangeEvent e){
    relationCompanyFileReferenceMB.getModel().setLookupCompany(lookupCompany);
    relationCompanyFileReferenceMB.getModel().setYear(year);
    relationCompanyFileReferenceMB.save();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the browser? Check with firebug or similar tool.

Comment: There is no error. Checked it.

Comment: Just tested on my PF 4.0 and the valueChangeListener is not calling. I also use fileUpload mode advanced in my app, but i never had to use the valueChangeListener...what are you trying to do?

Comment: I use PF 3.5. I try to update record when value change.

Comment: Are you implying that `fileUploadListener` method works fine? This is impossible based on the code given so far. *Both* the methods wouldn't be invoked at all in this construct.

Comment: fileUploadListener works fine. I used it in several project.